# Multiple divs with background color behind text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a background color behind text. I'll have multiple elements like this.

The current problem I'm experiencing is that, to have the background color "fit" the text, I'm using the 'display: inline' property. However, the problem is that for the next element, I need it to show up on a new line, not on the same line.

How it current is:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jLVRfwk.png]

How I need it:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dXyXNSa.png]

Here's the JSFiddle I started: [**http://jsfiddle.net/KFYyd/5/**](http://jsfiddle.net/KFYyd/5/)

HTML:

```
<div class="text">This is text.</div>
<div class="text">This is text.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
  display: inline;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just float the divs and clear on both

```
.text {
  float:left;
  clear:both;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Display the divs as inline-block and add a line break between them.

HTML:

```
<div class="text">This is text.</div><br>
<div class="text">This is text.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: table`, it has the same shrinkwrap properties of inline-block, but forces the elements to appear on their own line.

http://jsfiddle.net/KFYyd/5/

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.text {
    display: table;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Unlike using floats, you don't have to worry about clearing, which can sometimes cause problems with layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Add a clearfix to clear float after itself. This is useful where elements are stacked horizontally.

HTML :

```
<div class="text">This is text.</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="text">This is text.</div>
```

CSS :

```
.text {
    display: inline;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Just use that method once you understand what is happening.

[Read more about float - by Chris Coyer](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)